# entity framework 6 вставка связанных сущеостей

Tags: entity-framework

Есть несколько сущностей: operation, batch и sale_price. Я хочу добавить новую операцию, с новым батчем и новой ценой.

```
 Batch newBatch = new Batch
            {
                Product = product,
                Product_Code = product.Code,
                Purchase = Helper.ConvertAndRound(Purchase.Text),
                Quantity = Helper.ConvertAndRound(Quantity.Text),
                Create_Time = now
            };         
Sale_Price sale_Price = new Sale_Price
            {
                Sale = Helper.ConvertAndRound(Sale.Text),
                Product = product,
                Product_Code = product.Code,
                Start_Date = now,
                End_Date = null
            };
operation = new Operation
            {
                Batch = newBatch,
                Sale_Price = sale_Price,
                Quantity = Helper.ConvertAndRound(Quantity.Text),
                Discount = 0
            };
```

Добавление в бд:

```
 myContext.Operations.AddRange(operations);                        
 myContext.SaveChanges();
```

Все сущности добавляются, но связи не проставляются (у Operation Batch_id = null и sale_price = null). Настройка связей вроде правильная, т.к если в бд есть связи, то он их подгружает.

Если проставлять id костылем, то все работает:

```
myContext.Operations.AddRange(operations);                 
myContext.SaveChanges();
foreach (Operation operation in operations)
{
        operation.Batch_Id = operation.Batch.Id;
        operation.Sale_Price_Id = operation.Sale_Price.Id;
}
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался. Видимо я допустил ошибку в описании моделей, что странно, ведь все связанные сущности и данные он загружал правильно. Сейчас сделал генерацию БД на основе кода, было много ошибок. Исправил их и все заработало.